# Powershell rename multiple files in bulk (replace .txt with _,txt)

Tags: powershell, cmd

How to Rename multiple files that I have from 1.txt, 2.txt to something like 1_A.txt 2_A.txt
I tried the code below but it didn't work

```bsh
dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace ".txt ","_A.txt"}
```

Can someone give me some guidance how to do this, since I have 100 files to rename

Comment: There's a trailing space in your search regex. Also, for robustness you should escape `.` as `\.` and anchor the match at the end of the string (`$`): `dir | rename-item -NewName { $_.name -replace '\.txt$', '_A.txt' }`

Answer (score 1):

…and based upon your [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) tag:

```
for %I in ("*.txt") do @ren "%I" "%~nI_A%~xI"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell:

```
 Replace:
             $_.name -replace ".txt ","_A.txt"
      To: 
             ($_.basename+'_A.txt')
```

---

```
 ls *.txt | ? {ren $_.fullname -New ($_.basename+'_A.txt')}
```